Expected value of rectified linear function over white noise
I wondered if anyone could handle a rectified linear function's expectation.
Looking online, I found this solution, which I assume is correct for one-dimensional $x$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-b x^2} d x=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 b^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
This could be helpful if we were dealing with one-dimensional data points. There are already solved integrals for multi-dimensional data points but not for rectified linear functions. Here's an example:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^{\top} A x+b^{\top} x+c\right) d^n x=\sqrt{\operatorname{det}\left(2 \pi A^{-1}\right)} e^{\frac{1}{2} b^{\top} A^{-1} b+c}
$$
Is there a generalisation of this answer?
More specifically, I'm looking for a solution to the below integral:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n>0}^\infty x \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} x^{\top} A x+b^{\top} x+c\right) d^n x
$$
where $x$ is a vector, and $A$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix.
Thanks.
